# React Keycloak, Offline Support in PWA

Tags: reactjs, keycloak, progressive-web-apps

### Update after adjusting the config according to [this issue](https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular/issues/53#issuecomment-898231568) @abraham found

I adjusted my KeycloakProvider so that it looks now like this:

```js
<ReactKeycloakProvider
      authClient={keycloakInstance}
      LoadingComponent={<LoaderComponent fullscreen />}
      initOptions={{
        onLoad: "login-required",
        checkLoginIframe: false,
        flow: "hybrid",
        enableLogging: true,
        token: localStorage.getItem("XXXX-keycloak-token"),
        idToken: localStorage.getItem("XXXX-keycloak-idtoken"),
        refreshToken: localStorage.getItem("XXXX-keycloak-refreshtoken"),
      }}
      onEvent={(evt, msg) => console.log(evt, msg)}
      onTokens={(evt) => {
        evt.token && localStorage.setItem("XXXX-keycloak-token", evt.token);
        evt.idToken &&
          localStorage.setItem("XXXX-keycloak-idtoken", evt.idToken);
        evt.refreshToken &&
          localStorage.setItem(
            "XXXX-keycloak-refreshtoken",
            evt.refreshToken
          );
      }}
    >
```

The tokens are getting saved to the localStorage correctly but when I reload the app in an offline state there is an `onAuthRefreshError` followed by an `onAuthError` which redirects me to the URL `https://secure-XXXX.de/auth/realms/XXX/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=client&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F&state=927c90f5-839a-40ff-8910-13fb5870b4d5&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code%20id_token%20token&scope=openid&nonce=2c7ae016-fab8-4fa0-8c02-ef9147f598d0` which isn't possible because I'm offline... it seems that the passing of the tokens can't be correctly validated by the framework so that the provider still doesn't get initialized correctly?

### Original question

I'm currently working on a react based (PWA) application which utilizes keycloak for authentication and authorization. I'm trying to implement offline capabilities with the help of a workbox powered service worker (with the configuration as specified below). I'm also succesfully issuing offline tokens to the client and the online request to the realm URL is cached sucesfully.

I configured the default created (CRA) service worker as:

```js
registerRoute(
  ({ url }) => url.hostname.includes("secure-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.de"),
  new NetworkFirst({
    cacheName: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    plugins: [new ExpirationPlugin({ maxAgeSeconds: 3600 })], // TODO adjust duration for prod
  })
);
```

also I configured the Keycloak login scope to issue offline tokens:

```js
keycloak.login({ scope: "offline_access" })
```

When visiting the on the dev server deployed app you can see the service worker registering and caching the request to the `auth/realms/{...}/account` API. As soon as I'm switching to offline and reloading the page everything works fine until keycloak tries to open the URL `https://secure-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.de/auth/realms/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/protocol/openid-connect/login-status-iframe.html/init?client_id=client&origin=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx` which seems to be issued by the `login-status-iframe.html`.

I guess that this call leads to the Keycloak instance not properly initiated which means that the Loading component which I defined in the `ReactKeycloakProvider` does not close -> **the app is not usable in offline mode**.

Here are the relevant versions I'm using:

```json
"@react-keycloak/web": "^3.4.0",
"@types/react": "^16.14.3",
"@types/react-dom": "^16.9.10",
"keycloak-js": "^12.0.2",
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"workbox-background-sync": "^5.1.4",
"workbox-broadcast-update": "^5.1.4",
"workbox-cacheable-response": "^5.1.4",
"workbox-core": "^5.1.4",
"workbox-expiration": "^5.1.4",
"workbox-google-analytics": "^5.1.4",
"workbox-navigation-preload": "^5.1.4",
"workbox-precaching": "^5.1.4",
"workbox-range-requests": "^5.1.4",
"workbox-routing": "^5.1.4",
"workbox-strategies": "^5.1.4",
"workbox-streams": "^5.1.4"
```

What am I missing so that I can use my PWA offline?
Thank you for help

[Image of the Browser Cache State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1pTl.png)

[Image of the Keycloak UI which shows the issued tokens are offline tokens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmBqo.png)

Comment: The offline_access scope is unrelated to offline PWAs. It is for servers to make requests on behalf of users that are not actively using the service. [Ref](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_offline-access)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @abraham I thought it means that the issued cookie can be used in an offline state. But am I right that changing the code by deleting the `offline_access` part won't fix the problem?

Comment: It looks like there is a way to [disable the iframe feature](https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular/issues/53#issuecomment-898231568).

Comment: Thanks @abraham for referencing this issue! I adjusted my code according to the post and also tried to solve the issue by adjusting some other params but unfortionally that also doesnt word :/ I update the question with the new config maybe you have another idea?

Comment: @Max Did you find a solution ? I'm facing the same problem right now.